# Snakemake absolute file paths not recognized in rule when file path specified as target

Tags: absolute-path, snakemake

Snakefile:

`rule A:
    output: "/Volumes/rnaseq/x.txt"`

Command:

`snakemake -s t1 /Volumes/rnaseq/x.txt`

Output:

`MissingRuleException:
No rule to produce ../../../../../../../Volumes/rnaseq/x.txt (if you use input functions make sure that they don't raise unexpected exceptions).`

Why is this happening?  Is this a SnakeMake bug?  Does it have a problem matching the file with the rule because it puts the ../..... into the filename?

Comment: Yes, it is a bug, and it is fixed in the current master. Sorry for the inconvenience. In general it is advisable to avoid absolute paths though (except in config files or sample sheets), because it limits portability/reproducibility of the workflow.

Comment: Thanks.  I use an absolute path because the files are on an external hard drive.  What would be the right way to avoid using absolute paths in that case?

Comment: By putting the absolute path in a config file instead of hardcoding it into the workflow, others (or you, later) can easily port the workflow to a different place, by only modifying the config file. Btw. the bugfix is in Snakemake 4.1.0 that I released Tuesday.

Comment: Yes, I do that.  The example here was just to illustrate the problem.